# How to pass an array made of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm just trying to write a simple code where I enter a 3 letter word and then print out the word I entered. I tried doing this by creating the array, and then making a loop where the counter "i" keeps incrementing and the scan function keeps working for each index value of the letter I add. 
But there seems to be some error in line 16, and even then not sure if the logic of the code is right.

````
#include <string.h>
#define ALEN 3
int main (void)
{
    char array[ALEN];
    int i;
    printf("Enter a 3 letter word> ");
    scanf("%s", array);
    for(i=0; i<ALEN; i++)
    {
        array[i] = array[ALEN];
        scanf("%s", &array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Word entered: %s", char array[i]);
return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Your array is three characters long. That doesn't allow it to hold three three-character words (much less the NULL terminators for each).

Comment: This is not an array of three character strings, this is an array of literally three characters. You have some more C fundamentals to absorb here. Do you have a good reference?

Comment: **1** If you want to have a 3 letter word printed, you need 4 spaces; 3 for the letters & 1 for the string terminator `\0`. **2** `array[i] = arrat[ALEN]` is buggy. Your array is defined to have 3 char elements, having indices 0, 1, 2; but `ALEN` is defined as '3'.

Comment: besides you'll have to account for the case when users enter a string longer than 3 letters